# Ignore redmine prompt when building dockerfile

Tags: docker, redmine, dockerfile

I'm building docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:wily

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ruby 1.9.3
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-passenger
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y redmine redmine-mysql
```

The last command will install Redmine and it will prompt to ask for config the database connection like this:
Package configuration

```
 ┌──────────────────────────┤ Configuring redmine ├──────────────────────────┐  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ The redmine/instances/default package must have a database installed and  │  
 │ configured before it can be used.  This can be optionally handled with    │  
 │ dbconfig-common.                                                          │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ If you are an advanced database administrator and know that you want to   │  
 │ perform this configuration manually, or if your database has already      │  
 │ been installed and configured, you should refuse this option.  Details    │  
 │ on what needs to be done should most likely be provided in                │  
 │ /usr/share/doc/redmine/instances/default.                                 │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ Otherwise, you should probably choose this option.                        │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │ Configure database for redmine/instances/default with dbconfig-common?    │  
 │                                                                           │  
 │                    <Yes>                       <No>                       │  
 │                                                                           │  
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Q: I don't know how to say no to this when building Dockerfile. I just want to ignore this, keep running other command and configure database connection late.

Answer (score 0):

RUN apt-get install -y redmine redmine-mysql => RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y redmine redmine-mysql